# .NET 7 one-to-many relationship with foreign key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting an error on the migration and cannot figure out why. I'm trying to setup the relationship in which each country in the country table can have many relationships with cars from the car table.

**DbContext**

```
using API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
        
        public DbSet<CarModel> Cars => Set<CarModel>();
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<CarModel>(b => b.HasKey(c => new {c.Id, c.PublicId}));
            
            builder.Entity<CarModel>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Country)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<CountryModel>(c => c.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

**CarRepository**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class CarRepo : ICarRepo
    {
        
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        public CarRepo(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CarModel>> GetAllCars()
        {
            return await _context.Cars!.OrderBy(c => c.CreatedOn).ThenBy(c => c.WMI).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<CarModel?> GetCarById(string id)
        {
            return await _context.Cars!.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.PublicId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**CarModel**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class CarModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PublicId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
        public virtual CountryModel? Country { get; set; }
        public string? WMI { get; set; }
        public string? VehicleType { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateAvailableToPublic { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CountryModel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace API.Models
{
    public class CountryModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CarReadDto**

```
namespace API.DTOs
{
    public class CarReadDto
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Country { get; set; }
        public string? WMI { get; set; }
        public string? VehicleType { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateAvailableToPublic { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CarsProfile(Automapper)**

```
using API.DTOs;
using API.Models;
using AutoMapper;

namespace API.Profiles
{
    public class CarsProfile : Profile
    {
        public CarsProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CarModel, CarReadDto>()
                .ForMember(crd => crd.Id, o => o.MapFrom(cm => cm.PublicId))
                .ForMember(crd => crd.Country, o => o.MapFrom(cm => cm.Country!.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

**Seed**

```
using System.Globalization;
using API.Models;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class Seed
    {
        public static async Task SeedData(AppDbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Cars.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("seeding...");
                var countries = new List<CountryModel>
                {
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "UNITED STATES"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "CANADA"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        Name = "UNITED KINGDOM"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 4,
                        Name = "MEXICO"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 5,
                        Name = "BELGIUM"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 6,
                        Name = "CHINA"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 7,
                        Name = "JAPAN"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 8,
                        Name = "SPAIN"
                    },
                    new CountryModel
                    {
                        Id = 9,
                        Name = "HONG KONG"
                    },
                };
                
                var cars = new List<CarModel>
                {
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = null,
                        Country = null,
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Rosco Dealer",
                        UpdatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-06-04", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        VehicleType = "Passenger Car",
                        WMI = "ENI"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[0].Id,
                        Country = countries[0],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "Rusty Buckets",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Passenger Car",
                        WMI = "4PC"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[1].Id,
                        Country = countries[1],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 3,
                        Name = "My Used Cars",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Passenger Car",
                        WMI = "2MV"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[2].Id,
                        Country = countries[2],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 4,
                        Name = "Honky Cheers",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Passenger Car",
                        WMI = "3WD"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[3].Id,
                        Country = countries[3],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 5,
                        Name = "Hola Cars",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Passenger Car",
                        WMI = "DIS"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[4].Id,
                        Country = countries[4],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-03", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 6,
                        Name = "Chop Shop",
                        UpdatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-07-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        VehicleType = "Motorcycle",
                        WMI = "IUS"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[5].Id,
                        Country = countries[5],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-06-04", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-04-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 7,
                        Name = "Cheap Riders",
                        UpdatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-08-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        VehicleType = "Motorcycle",
                        WMI = "ENV"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[6].Id,
                        Country = countries[6],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-06-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-06-08", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 8,
                        Name = "Yakuza Shop",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Motorcycle",
                        WMI = "VIE"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[7].Id,
                        Country = countries[7],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-06-17", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-06-17", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 9,
                        Name = "Quality Riders",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Motorcycle",
                        WMI = "WJH"
                    },
                    new CarModel
                    {
                        CountryId = countries[8].Id,
                        Country = countries[8],
                        CreatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-10-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        DateAvailableToPublic = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-10-26", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Id = 10,
                        Name = "Cheap Mobile Homes",
                        UpdatedOn = null,
                        VehicleType = "Trailer",
                        WMI = "5SD"
                    }
                };

                await context.Cars.AddRangeAsync(cars);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below I get the following error:

[image]

### Update

I've made the following changes as Ivan Stoev suggested...

**Seed**

```
await context.Cars.AddRangeAsync(cars);
await context.Countries.AddRangeAsync(countries); <-- added this line
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**AppDbContext**

```
using API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
        
        public DbSet<CarModel> Cars => Set<CarModel>();
        public DbSet<CountryModel> Countries => Set<CountryModel>();
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<CarModel>(b => b.HasKey(c => new {c.Id, c.PublicId}));
            
            builder.Entity<CarModel>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Country)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryId);
            
            builder.Entity<CountryModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

However, for the http request the country values are all coming back as null:

[image]

Comment: Hi.  Your question probably needs the EF Core hashtag.

Comment: `.HasOne(c => c.Country).WithOne()` means one-to-one. and you need one-to-many, i.e. `.WithMany()`

Comment: @IvanStoev if I change it to `.WithMany()`, then `.HasForeignKey<CountryModel>(c => c.Id)` gives the following ide error: `The non-generic method 'ReferenceCollectionBuilder<CountryModel, CarModel>.HasForeignKey(params string[])' cannot be used with type arguments [API]csharp(CS0308)`

Comment: @FiddleFreak You should remove that as well. To be precise and explicit, it should be `.HasForeignKey(car => car.CountryId)`. The whole config: `builder.Entity<CarModel>().HasOne(c => c.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryId);`

Comment: @IvanStoev I made that update, but I'm still seeing the issue in the `Updated` part of the question

Comment: @IvanStoev So I fixed the sql query to be `ON Cars.CountryId = Countries.Id;` instead of before `ON Cars.CountryId = Countries.Id;`. The data is mapping correctly, however, the api response is still receiving null values for the http request(via postman)

Comment: I found the issue, there is a repository file where I had to add `_context.Cars!.Include(c => c.Country)`.